# completing the square equation

Tags: roots, square-numbers

Alright i came upon this problem while tutoring today and it just messed me up.

$$a^2 - 8a + 15 = 0$$

we start by adding 1 to both sides and get

$$a^2 - 8a + 16 = 1$$

then change the left side to

$$(a-4)^2 = 1$$

then take the square root of both sides to get

$$\pm (a - 4) = \pm 1$$

then solve for $a$ in $a - 4 = 1$ to get $$a = 5$$ and $-(a - 4) = -1$ to

get $$a = 5$$

making the answer only one root which is impossible here.

The right answer should be $(5,3)$ but I can't seem to understand how to get $3$. What am I forgetting? Thanks for the help

Comment: The solutions to $(a-4)^2=1$  are $a-4=\pm 1$ or $a=\{3,5\}$

Comment: Indeed, you could have just factored the original quadratic as $(a-3)(a-5)=0$.

Comment: We simply do not have $$x^2=y\implies \pm x=\pm\sqrt y$$ as you suggest.

Comment: hahaha yep im not sure why id did that. i knew i was doing something stupid. thanks

Comment: @JoshuaJohn I would contest the claim that this is a stupid mistake. It shows thought and consideration despite leading you astray.

Comment: The only mistake that you made was writing $$\pm (a - 4) = \pm 1 ~~\text{instead of}~~ (a - 4) = \pm 1.$$

Comment: The way I usually complete the square is to bring the constant term to the right, then halve the $a$ term, square it, and add to both sides.  This will give you the factoring (which you did correctly!) you need before you take the square root of both sides.  When you take square roots, however, you don't need to apply "$\pm$" to both sides, just the constant term after the equals sign.